# Python XML regular expression matching issue

Tags: python, xml, regex

I have been trying to match **tag names only** (without the `<` and `>` signs) is cases of regular tags:

`<w:tag w:attrib1="http://url" w:attrib2="anyValue">`

without matching solo tags (opening-closing tags):

`<w:tag2 w:attrib1="anyValue" w:attrib2="http://url" />`

(please pay attention to the **URLs** in the attributes as they contain forward slashes (`/`))

but could not manage to get to it with:

`regex = re.compile('(?<=<)w:\w+(?=[\w\W]+>)(?!\s/>)')`

`print(regex.findall(string))`

getting this:

`['w:tag','w:tag2']`

expecting this:

`['w:tag']`

any thoughts?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it:

```
regex = re.compile('(?<=<)w:\w+(?=>)|(?<=<)w:\w+(?=[\s\w+:\w+="[\w/:.-]+"]{0,10}>)')
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Go easy on the lookahead/lookbehind; they're hard to control and you rarely really need them. Use capturing groups to extract part of the matched string. Use negative character classes and non-greedy search (if needed) to avoid matching too much:

```
re.findall(r'<\s*(w:\w+)[^>]*(?<!/)>', string)
```

Easier to read, isn't it? However,

2) Don't do this at all! Don't rely on REs to match XML or html, you're just asking for heartbreak. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/699305 for the details. :-) Get familiar with using python's `xml.etree.ElementTree` with xpath expressions instead. It'll take some getting used to, but it will be time well spent-- you won't regret it.

Comment: I know XML and lxml too well and loving it. Although this time I Need to handle some broken stuff... thanks for your detailed answer. It works like charm and indeed looks better than what I've come up with.